# How to use Apache server with statically linked binaries

Tags: apache2, webserver

I have a github repository that has C++ source code which after running cmake and make commands builds statically linked binaries. These binaries are used with a webpage called index.html created in HTML.

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I installed the latest Apache server like [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#2-installing-apache).

I deployed the website and I can get to the index.html when I go to localhost on my computer.

One of the binaries is called multiple search. It is called by the HTML page like:

```
<form action="cgi-bin/multiple_search" method="POST">
\\ multiple input tags
<input type="submit" value="Multiple search">
</form>
```

However, when I click on the multiple search submit button, I get the response as type octet-stream which is downloaded as a file that I don't know how to open.

This is what my .conf file looks like for this website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
ServerName mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/snapstream-searcher
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
#    <Location /cgi-bin>
#    Options ExecCGI SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#    ForceType text/html
#    AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
#    DefaultType 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
#    SetEnv no-gzip 1
#    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried forcing the server to return the page as text/html;iso-8859-1 (this is what is expected) by modifying the .conf file, however, that returns a page full of weird characters instead of expected text as follows:

[Weird characters displayed on webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqN88.png)

What settings should the .conf file have to work with binary file output?

Comment: Why is the cgi-bin configuration commented out with `#`?

Comment: You want Apache to execute the file instead of downloading it. 
See the `Configuring Apache to permit CGI` section of the [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html). You might find it helpful to add `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` and add the `.cgi` extension to your binary.

Comment: Thanks @dan , I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dan's comment put me on the right track with **the Configuring Apache to permit CGI** section of the [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html).

My final .conf file looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/snapstream

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/snapstream/cgi-bin">

Options +ExecCGI

<FilesMatch "^[^.]+$">

SetHandler cgi-script

</FilesMatch>

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In my case, my binary files did not have an extension, so I had to use the FilesMatch tag to define that all files that did not have an extension in a particular directory were binaries and should be handled with a cgi-script.

cgi.load is the module for CGI files. It is not enabled by default. The most essential step to get the binaries running instead of downloading was to enable that module. I found the steps for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942790/python-cgi-script-is-downloading-instead-of-running).